# dependent dropdown in wordpress theme files

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to create state/city dependent dropdown in wordpress. This is my js file code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#state').change(function(){

var $location = $(this).val();
alert($location);
$.ajax({
url:'ajaxurl',
type: 'post',
data: ({action : 'getcity'}),
success: function() {

$("#district").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#district").append(results);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

I have created function called getcity in function.php and add hooks and action to that function and add this js file to theme js folder and enque it in function file. I m getting empty alert ?? Anybody has any idea??

```
add_action('wp_head','ajaxurl');
function ajaxurl() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."getcity"; ?>';
</script>
```

this is dropdown code

```
<p class="half_form half_form_last">
                <label for="property_country"><?php _e('State ','wpestate'); ?></label>
                <select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2">
          <option  value="">Select state</option>
                <?php 
                $result=$wpdb->get_results("select distinct(state) from tblcitylist");
                //$wpdb->get_results($query);
                foreach($result as $row) {
$state=$row->state;
echo '<option value="">'.$state.'</option>';
}

          ?>      
            </select>    

            </p>
```

In function.php

```
function getcity(){
    global $wpdb;
    if($_POST['state'])
            {
                $id=$_POST['state'];

                $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tblcitylist WHERE  
 state='$id'");
                //$wpdb->get_results($query);
                              foreach($result as $row) {
                                                             $city_name   = $row- 
>city_name;
                             $city_id     = $row->city_id;

                            echo '<option  
  value="'.$city_id.'">'.$city_name.'</option>';
                //echo '<option value="'.'0'.'">'.'New Phase'.'</option>';

            }
 }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

I have included js file as follows in functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script('my_own_js', 
get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my_own_js.js',array('jquery'));
```

Comment: Where do you define `ajaxurl`?
Is it empty or 0?

Comment: please see edit and i include that in template file.

Comment: Try this `var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."?action=getcity"; ?>';`

Comment: Well, since you have the action in the `$_POST`. You don't need it in the `$_GET`: `var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';`

Comment: what about empty alert..should i delete that ajaxurl code from template file??

Comment: That means it can't get the current value of the DropDown. Could you post the code of the Dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to post it as an answer. I'd delete the `var ajaxurl` from the functions.php and use it inside the page. Then I don't see where you pass the location to the `ajax`. It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#state').on('change', function() {

      var location = this.value;
      alert(location);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        data: ({'action' : 'getcity', 'location' : location }),
        success: function(results) {
          $("#district").removeAttr("disabled");
          $("#district").append(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

then the Dropdown should look like this

```
<select id="state">
  <option value="state1">state1</option>
  <option value="state2">state2</option>
  ...
</select>
```

And for the `getcity` you have to get the right `$_POST`:

```
function getcity(){
global $wpdb;
  if($_POST['location']){
    $id=$_POST['location'];
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tblcitylist WHERE state='$id'");
    $html = '';
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $city_name = $row->city_name;
      $city_id   = $row->city_id;
      $html .= '<option value="'.$city_id.'">'.$city_name.'</option>';
    }
  }
}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

Comment: alert is empty and district dropdown is also empty. I m getting state dropdown from database but I want district dropdown dependent on state selected.

Comment: Great. Now I need the code of your `getcity` function to see whats wrong with the result. Just add it to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59251/discussion-between-nico-martin-and-kedar-b).